# Where should I ask question related to micro-controller ?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If I need some information about micro-controller for my project as per my requirement then,

- Where should I ask this question ?
- Which site is best to post this question, So, I can get proper answer ?
- Can I ask this question on Stack Overflow ?

Comment: May be here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What kind of question?

Comment: When you mention requirements just make sure it's not a product recommendation - they are offtopic so check the help pages first. You may be able to pose it as asking what microcontroller features you need to do a specific task and that would be fine.

Comment: I am new in micro-controller and I am going to create my first project. So, I need some information like what kind of micro-controller should i use to create a device with infrared receiver.

Comment: If it's an Arduino there is http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Nimesh, you might be better to ask that in EE chat - it's fairly broad and opinion based - reality is just about any microcontroller could do that. Perhaps the Arduino would be a good place to start for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks @asawyer, Your information is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Where should I ask this question ?
>   Which site is best to post this question, So, I can get proper answer ?

[Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), here you can ask questions about micro-controller and you will  get proper answer.

> Can I ask this question on Stack Overflow ?

No, you can't ask about this on Stack Overflow.Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers

Answer (score 3):

You should ask micro-controller related question on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) site.

Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. So you shouldn't ask it there.